# I can't reach customers AdWords Account with Google Login

Tags: google-ads-api, google-signin

I want to connect -any- customer Google AdWords Account with Google Login. (Like Wordstream)

I prepared a code, but there is a problem somewhere, I can't run it.

When the customer press the connect button, the screen appears. It says "XXX wants to acces your Google Account", it is approved but I cannot receive data.

How can i get datas from customer's account?

Code:

```
require 'google-api/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Auth\OAuth2;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\CampaignService;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;

session_start();

$oauth2 = new OAuth2([
    
    'authorizationUri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
    'tokenCredentialUri' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    'redirectUri' => 'https://xxxxx.xxxxxx',
    'clientId' => 'xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'clientSecret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords',
    'refresh_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxx'
]);

if(!isset($_GET['code'])){
    
    $oauth2->setState(sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1024)));
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $oauth2->getState();

    $config = [
    
        'access_type' => 'offline',
        'prompt' => 'consent',

    ];
    
    header('Location: ' . $oauth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri($config));
    exit;
  
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])){
    
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state.');
  
} else {
    
    $oauth2->setCode($_GET['code']);
    $authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();
    $refreshToken = $authToken['refresh_token'];
    
    $path = "xxxxx/google-api/vendor/adsapi_php.ini";

    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile($path)
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oauth2)
        ->build();
    
    $adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
    
    $campaignService = $adWordsServices->get($session, CampaignService::class);
    
    print_r($campaignService);

}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "I cannot receive data"?
The code you list above doesn't download anything, it just constructs one of the service objects that allow you to interact with the Adwords API.

Comment: @dorian Actually i curios about how can i get customers google ads id after google login. i get just normal google id.

Comment: You can use the [`CustomerService`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#customerservice) for that purpose.